# Blank page shown using webview

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

Good day!
I have tried using webview for my app but it seems the result was blank. Sorry but this is my first try to use android studio.

Here's an example of my MainActivity.java code:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView web;
    String webUrl = "https://scchemp.rf.gd/";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myweb);
        web.loadUrl(webUrl);

        WebSettings mywebsettings = web.getSettings();
        mywebsettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        //improve webview performance
        web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        web.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        web.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        web.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mywebsettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mywebsettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        mywebsettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mywebsettings.setSavePassword(true);
        mywebsettings.setSaveFormData(true);
        mywebsettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(web.canGoBack()){
            web.goBack();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


}
```

For Manifest. I added android.permission.INTERNET and andriod.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE for permission

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.andriodscch.scchemisapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="andriod.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SCCHEMISAPP">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[Result Image Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM91m.png)

also the this is the activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <WebView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/myweb"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add the layout XML?

Comment: I've just added the layout.

Comment: Your layout seems ok. 
Maybe you have tried it, but try to comment out all the "settings" you have set to the webview.